# Python- need fast algorithm that removes all words in a file that are derivatives in other words

Tags: python, algorithm, list, io

We have a file named wordlist, which contains 1,876 KB worth of alphabetized words, all of which are longer than 4 letters and contain one carriage return between each new two-letter construction (ab, ac, ad, etc., words all contain returns between them):

```
 wfile = open("wordlist.txt", "r+")
```

I want to create a new file that contains only words that are not derivatives of other, smaller words.  For example, the wordlist contains the following words ["abuser, abused, abusers, abuse, abuses, etc.]   The new file that is created should retain only the word "abuse" because it is the "lowest common denominator" (if you will) between all those words.  Similarly, the word "rodeo" would be removed because it contains the word rode.

I tried this implementation:

```
def root_words(wordlist):
    result = []
    base = wordlist[1]
    for word in wordlist:
        if not word.startswith(base):
            result.append(base)
            print base
            base=word
    result.append(base)
    return result;


def main():
    wordlist = []
    wfile = open("wordlist.txt", "r+")

    for line in wfile:
        wordlist.append(line[:-1])

    wordlist = root_words(wordlist)
    newfile = open("newwordlist.txt", "r+")    
    newfile.write(wordlist)
```

But it always froze my computer.  Any solutions?

Comment: rodent will also be treated as a derivative of rode?  It seems a naive definition of derivative

Comment: have you had a look at stemming algorithms?

Comment: So if you add icecream before ice, it'll be a different result than if you do it the other way around? I think you need to reconsider your algorithm here.

Comment: @Will, I don't see how that could possibly contribute to the discussion/answer, but nevertheless appreciate your cynicism.  I could not think of a better explanation that conveyed the statement: "remove all words that contain smaller root words that appear only at the front of a word."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def bases(words):
    base = next(words)
    yield base
    for word in words:
        if word and not word.startswith(base):
            yield word
            base = word


def get_bases(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile) as f_in:
        words = (line.strip() for line in f_in)
        with open(outfile, 'w') as f_out:
            f_out.writelines(word + '\n' for word in bases(words))
```

This goes through the [corncob list](http://www.mieliestronk.com/wordlist.html) of 58,000 words in a fifth of a second on my fairly old laptop. It's old enough to have one gig of memory.

```
$ time python words.py

real        0m0.233s
user        0m0.180s
sys         0m0.012s
```

It uses iterators everywhere it can to go easy on the memory. You could probably increase performance by slicing off the end of the lines instead of using strip to get rid of the newlines.

Also note that this relies on your input being sorted and non-empty. That was part of the stated preconditions though so I don't feel *too* bad about it ;)

Comment: This worked extraordinarily fast, but one problem: the return carriages between each new letter construction makes it to where the "newfile.txt" stops after the first return.  Any way to resolve this?

Comment: @parseltongue. I don't know what you're talking about. Could you provide a concrete example of what you want the input to look like and what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I found a way to resolve this by editing the wordlist in Microsoft Word and replacing all ^p^p with ^p, and it removed all double carriage returns.  It would be nice to know how to just ignore the ^p^p programatically, though.

What happened previously is that there were double returns between each new double-letter construction.  For example,

aardvard
aardwolf
                << double return = blank space <<
abiogenesis
abuse 

So your algorithm would just stop when it came to the first double carriage return

P.S. Why is this so extrordinarily fast?

Comment: @Parseltongue, I see now. The version I put up _should_ do the trick with your original format. The trick is to check that the word's not blank (corresponding to a blank line) before we do anything with it.

Comment: It works, though I'm not sure how.  Why does adding "if word and not word.startswith(base):" change anything if one of the "words" is a blank line.

Comment: @ParselTongue. It works because before, when it ran into a blank work (i.e. an empty string), it used that as the new base because the old base was not contained in it. Now, it will just skip empty strings because if `word=''`, then `word` tests as false, and the old base isn't replaced.

Answer (score 2):

One possible improvement is to use a database to load the words and avoid loading the full input file in RAM. Another option is to process the words as you read them from the file and write the results without loading everything in memory.

The following example treats the file as it is read without pre-loading stuff in memory.

```
def root_words(f,out):
    result = []
    base = f.readline()
    for word in f:
        if not word.startswith(base):
            out.write(base + "\n")
            base=word
    out.write(base + "\n")

def main():
    wfile = open("wordlist.txt", "r+")
    newfile = open("newwordlist.txt", "w")
    root_words(wfile,newfile)
    wfile.close()
    newfile.close()
```

Memory complexity of this solution is O(1) since the variable `base` is the only thing that you need in order to process the file. This can be done thanks to that the file is alphabetically sorted.

Comment: That is not O(1) for time, just memory. It's O(n) for time. You need to look at every word but you only need to look at it once. Realistically, like mine, there will be more memory requirements than `base` because Python will buffer the file reads.

Comment: yep with complexity space I mean memory. I change the wording to avoid confusion.

Comment: and ... yes again ... I don't take into account how Python buffers reads but if implements caching based on memory page size it is again constant memory complexity.

Comment: Also, `file` objects don't have a `print` method. I think you want `write`. And you want to open the second file in `w` mode. After that, it runs and if you take the superfluous `print` statement out, it's only a little slower than mine ;)

Comment: @aaronasterling thanks for the 'print' thing ... ;) ... thanks for the feedback !!!! I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

since the list is alphabetized, this does the trick (takes 0.4seconds with 5 megs of data, so should not be a problem with 1.8)

```
res = [" "]

with open("wordlist.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        tmp = line.strip()
        if tmp.startswith(res[-1]):
            pass
        else:
            res.append(tmp)

with open("newlist.txt","w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(res[1:]))
```